# Is it possible to write my own Trust Agent?

Tags: android

Google Smart Lock is unreliable so I am thinking I will write my own Trust Agent to replace it.
Is that possible or will the OS prevent me from doing that?

I tried searching Google and Android Developers with no luck.

I am a reasonably competent Java programmer so I am sure I can figure out the code
if I can find the right documentation.

Comment: You might want to explain in detail what you mean by "Trust Agent".

Comment: I want to write a replacement for Smart Lock

Comment: Are you building your own firmware for your device, with a custom build of Android that contains your "replacement for Smart Lock"?

Comment: I am not planning to write my own firmware. Is that the only way to do it?

Comment: If you want it to be secure, yes.

Comment: OK, got it.  I guess I will have to find another answer.  Please put your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API in the Android SDK to replace a lockscreen implementation.